# Some code in my sub won't execute

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbdatareader

I have a sub in my program that removes items from my access database if their expiration date has passed. I am using an oledbdatareader to find the rows that need deleting. My problem is that most of this sub will not execute. I have used a messagebox to tell me that the code does not run after I have defined my datareader.

I have used this same code in many other functions and forms, and it works fine, but for some reason in this sub it doesn't. Can anyone see my problem?

```
Private Sub AutoDate()
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionstring)
        connection.Open()

        Dim Command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ExpirationDate FROM Iventory", connection)
        Dim Command2 As New OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Inventory WHERE ExpirationDate = @p1", connection)

        MessageBox.Show("Got here") 'This messagebox shows
        Dim Reader As OleDbDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
        MessageBox.Show("Got here") 'This messagebox does not show

        While Reader.Read()
                Dim ExpDate As DateTime = Reader.Item("ExpirationDate")
                Command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ExpDate)

                If ExpDate.ToString < System.DateTime.Today.ToString Then
                    Dim cmd = Command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    If cmd > 0 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Out of date items have been removed from database")
                    Else
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
        End While
        connection.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the command object. You are calling execute reader on this so it won't delete anything

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: that first SQL SELECT statement is incomplete; not sure what its purpose is if you are removing expired stuff

Comment: The first statement reads all the expiration dates from the inventory table so that I can check if it is before today's date

Comment: You don't need to *read all the expiration dates*. Your `DELETE` already checks to see if it's before the indicated date with the `WHERE` clause. Just pass today's date as the parameter to `Command2`. (And to make it much cleaner, you can change the `=` to `<=` and clean up any old ones you missed along the way.)

Comment: Oh I see, of course! How silly of me... Thank you very much; this has been puzzling me for a while!